# Laravel some css/js files return 404

Tags: laravel, deployment, assets

I'm not the first to have these symptoms.. but none of the causes I found so far seem to be the same as I am experiencing.

After I deployed my Laravel app some of the assets return a 404 status. I have checked the permissions for these files.

Other files in the same folder also loaded with the `asset()` method load just fine.

I have set up my app in a folder at the same level as `public_html` and copied the contents of `public/` to my `public_html/subdomain` folder.

The issue can be seen here: [Staging area](http://staging.venraytickets.nl)

This is my file structure for `public_html/subdomain/`:

```
|-- cgi-bin
|-- css
|   |-- account.css
|   |-- admin_custom.css
|   |-- app.css
|   |-- home.css
|   `-- nav.css
|-- favicon.ico
|-- images
|   |-- venray-bloeit-logo-black.png
|   |-- venray-bloeit-logo-white.png
|   `-- wave_footer.png
|-- index.php
|-- js
|   |-- account.js
|   |-- admin
|   |   |-- accounts.js
|   |   |-- admin.js
|   |   `-- dashboard.js
|   |-- app.js
|   |-- nav.js
|   `-- plugins
|       |-- backstretch.min.js
|       |-- jquery-3.2.1.min.js
|       `-- tinymce
|           |-- jquery.tinymce.min.js
|           
|-- robots.txt
|-- vendor
|   |-- adminlte
|   |   |-- css
|   |   |   `-- auth.css
|   |   |-- dist
|   |   |   |-- css
|   |   |   |   |-- AdminLTE.css
|   |   |   |   |-- AdminLTE.min.css
|   |   |   |   `-- skins
|   |   |   |       |-- skin-black-light.css
|   |   |   `-- js
|   |   |       |-- adminlte.js
|   |   |       `-- adminlte.min.js
|   |   |-- plugins
|   |   |   `-- iCheck
|   |   |       |-- icheck.js
|   |   |       `-- icheck.min.js
|   |   `-- vendor
|   |               `-- jquery.min.map
|   `-- notify
|       |-- danger.mp3
|       |-- info.mp3
|       |-- notify.css
|       `-- notify.js
`-- web.config
```

Comment: would you like to show your files structure?

Comment: Is there any issue with your webpages due to these errors or these css/js files are important for you? there is no css file **yamm.css** in your structure?

Comment: Actually the file is not in the folder for example home.js is not in js folder

Comment: Sorry this was really silly of me.. I forgot to update the `public_html/subdomain/` folder...

Comment: yes that was the problem :)